# How to plot a region bounded by three equations?

Tags: plotting, syntax

I'm very new to this website. I am having trouble plotting a 3 dimensional region bounded by these equations:

```
R = {y == x <= y == - x + 2 <= y == -Sqrt[1 - (x - 1)^2]}
```

The problem is that I know what command to use to do this, but it gives me a blank plot. If it helps my code is below, and I have *Mathematica* Version 7.0:

```
RegionPlot3D[
  y == x <= y == - x + 2 <= y == -Sqrt[1 - (x - 1)^2], 
  {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 2}, {z, -10, 10}]
```

If someone could lead me to the right direction or tell me what is wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What exactly are the three equations? It is not clear from the question.

Comment: Your equations are not stated properly... look at the help file for RegionPLot3D to get the form right. Also, your limits are not right because when Abs[x] is large, the Sqrt[ ] has complex values.

Comment: Could you help me figure out which equations go where and what limits should I use? My algebra is not too good, I am interested in seeing what the region looks like. I will appreciate any help anyone can give at this point.

Answer (score 3):

The region is defined in two dimensions. Insights from the 2D plot:

```
Plot[{x, 2 - x, -Sqrt[1 - (1 - x)^2], Sqrt[1 - (1 - x)^2]}, {x, -3, 
  3}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 200, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Red, Red, Black}]
```

[image]

The region of interest is bounded in red, Exploiting the coincidence of the intersection of the lines at (1,1), a point on the circle: the region can be plotted in 3D:

```
RegionPlot3D[
  y <= x && y <= 2 - x && (x - 1)^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 
   3}, {z, -3, 3}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

I have changed the plot range just to make visualization 'nicer':
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the visualization.. I had them written as inequalities but not in the form you have showed me here. I really appreciate your help, it is much much clearer. Thanks again, ubpdqn!